# Communication between Ruby on Rails 3 Web application and C++ Desktop application

Tags: c++, ruby, web-services, ruby-on-rails-3, qt

According to my requirement I need to provide a communication between a Desktop application developed on C++(QT Framework) and Web application developing on Rails 3.

The requirement is, **User can able to upload/download files from Desktop application to Rails application. These files I need to save in live database.**

For this requirement, I'm planning to develop an API(Possibly Web Service). First of all is it possible to complete this requirement through Web Services using SOAP/WSDL/REST.

Please let me know the different ways to achieve this.

Thanks,
Kalyan

Comment: yes it's possible, yes there are other ways. What specific issue do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Rails provides a really nice way of developing an API with it's supported REST protocol. This way you can easy develop a web front end while essentially completing the API at the same time, this way your desktop application can communicate via the API.

As long as you keep your code [DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), your API can co-exist within your same web project. This way you don't have two separate code projects to maintain. This will help with consistency.